# Gson serialize POJO with root value included?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I'm having a problem serializing an object using Gson.

```
@XmlRootElement
class Foo implements Serializable {
    private int number;
    private String str;

    public Foo() {
        number = 10;
        str = "hello";
    }
}
```

Gson will serialize this into a JSON

`{"number":10,"str":"hello"}`.

However, I want it to be

`{"Foo":{"number":10,"str":"hello"}}`,

so basically including the top level element. I tried to google a way to do this in Gson, but no luck. Anyone knows if there is a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add the element at the top of the the object tree. Something like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement je = gson.toJsonTree(new Foo());
JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
jo.add("Foo", je);
System.out.println(jo.toString());
// Prints {"Foo":{"number":10,"str":"hello"}}
```

Comment: well, this means i need to hardcode the class type "Foo" into the element though.

Comment: @fei yes. Ideally, what You are getting from Gson is correct. The correct representation of `Foo` object in JSON is `{"number":10,"str":"hello"}`. If there is a class which has Foo as it's instance variable in that case you should have expected `{"foo":{"number":10,"str":"hello"}}` -- but if you want to prepend class name explicitly, you will have to add it explicitly.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of hardcoding the type you can do:

```
...
jo.add(Foo.getClass().getSimpleName(), je);
```

Comment: I think this should be a comment of the other answer and not an answer by itself. It is actually a good comment though

Answer (score 8):

A better way to do this is to create a wrapper class and then create an object of `Foo` inside it.

Sample code:

```
public class ResponseWrapper {

   @SerializedName("Foo")
   private Foo foo;

   public Foo getFoo() {
      return foo;
   }

   public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
      this.foo= foo;
   }
 }
```

Then you can easily parse to JSON using:

```
new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(responseWrapperObj);
```

which will give you the desired structure:

```
{"Foo":{"number":10,"str":"hello"}}
```

Comment: This is a much better response.

Comment: Not really, you're creating another object… in a small app with 3 models this is ok, but maintain 40+ and write these wrappers …

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Jackson api use the below lines

mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

Comment: The title of the question state's op is using GSON and not jackson