# gson - include class name when serializing java pojo -> json

Tags: java, json, gson

Using [GSON](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/Home) how do I append the class name of my List to my outputted json string? I've looked through the [api](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) and have missed any reference to do this. I'm using [GsonBuilder](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) in my real code but don't see any options for it either.

```
public class Person {
  String name;

  public Person(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args){
    Person one = new Person("Alice");
    Person two = new Person("Bob");

    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    people.add(one);
    people.add(two); 

    String json = new Gson(people);
  }
}
```

This gives the following output:

> json = [{"name": "Alice"},{"name": "Bob"}]

**How do I achieve the following output?** or something similar.

> json = {"person":[{"name": "Alice"},{"name": "Bob"}]}

or

> json = [{"person":{"name": "Alice"}},{"person":{"name": "Bob"}}]

Hope it's something trivial that I have just missed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simplest solution could be creation of some other class, which would contain some variable (or list of type person) with name "person".

Comment: This question addresses pretty the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623329/gson-serialize-pojo-with-root-value-included
and the accepted answer is also pretty the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if the answer is still interesting you but what you can do is the following:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Person one = new Person("Alice");
    Person two = new Person("Bob");

    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    people.add(one);
    people.add(two); 

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement je = gson.toJsonTree(people);
    JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
    jo.add("person", je);
    System.out.println(jo.toString()); //prints {"person":[{"name": "Alice"},{"name": "Bob"}]}
}
```