# How to include the name of the class when exporting a List of objects to JSON?

Tags: java, json, list, gson

My `dog` class look like this:

```
class Dog {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

I convert its `List` of objects to JSON:

```
List<Dog> myDogs = (Some initialization);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString=gson.toJson(myDogs);
```

The JSON string gives me this result:

```
[[{"id":1,"name":"Bull Dog"}],[{"id":2,"name":"German Shepherd"}]]
```

I want this string to include the class name `Dog` in the beginning, so that I can reparse it to a `List` of `Dog` objects on the client side.

I tried:

```
gson.toJsonTree(myDogs,Dog.class)
```

But no luck.

Comment: yes it is. I am sorry

Comment: np, good luck with it :)

Comment: Should each Dog-Object contain the class name or only the List of all Dogs? Also your JSON doesnt look like the class you provide. It is a List containing other Lists!?

Answer (score 0):

You can use toString() in your Dog class as suggested in [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272516/gson-include-class-name-when-serializing-java-pojo-json?lq=1)