# GSON deserialize POJO with root value included

Tags: json, gson, json-deserialization

I would like to achieve the opposite of this:
[Gson serialize POJO with root value included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623329/gson-serialize-pojo-with-root-value-included)

I get a JSON String

```
{"RootDTO":{"classField_01":"value"}}
```

and would like to deserialise that to

```
class RootDTO {
    String classField_01;
    //nice getter and setter are included
}
```

I know how to set the parameter so that in serialisation the root element is included into the JSON string.
But how to deserialise that now? Searching like hell already but wasn't able to find a suitable answer.

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: I think this is what you looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004338/skip-root-element-while-deserializing-json

Answer (score 0):

make `RootDTO.java`

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class RootDTO {

    @SerializedName("classField_01")
    private String classField_01;

    public String getClassField_01() {
        return classField_01;
    }

    public void setClassField_01(String classField_01) {
        this.classField_01 = classField_01;
    }
}
```

make `Response.java`

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Response {

    @SerializedName("RootDTO")
    private RootDTO rootDTO;

    public RootDTO getRootDTO() {
        return rootDTO;
    }

    public void setRootDTO(RootDTO rootDTO) {
        this.rootDTO = rootDTO;
    }
}
```

test this code to generate your json data

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class TestOne {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RootDTO dto = new RootDTO();
        dto.setClassField_01("value");
        Response response = new Response();
        response.setRootDTO(dto);

        String result = (new Gson()).toJson(response);
        System.out.println(""+result);
    }
}
```

output generated with this code

```
{"RootDTO":{"classField_01":"value"}}
```

Comment: Hi Pankaj, thank you for your comment. But I want the other way around and best with a solution where I don't need to create an extra class. But maybe I can just make the Response class of a generic type - might work.
Your way btw is easier to achieve with: mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

Comment: @Manuel, you are right about it, I have seen SimpleFramework work like that but it is only for the **xml** parsing, I wish I could help you with that, Apparently Gson has different approach at looking in **JSON**  data. If I learn to do what you want I will inform you.